# Discord Bot: Creating synonyms for text strings

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Hello everyone I have begun working on my bot for discord and I am very new to this but I was hoping to get some help figuring out if it was possible to set a const or something that would evaluate the "help" in the first part of the if statement as "help" or something else of my choosing like "ayuda" so that way no matter if they write help or ayuda the if statement would work (without creating a different argument).

The reason I ask is I plan to have a few if statements that will use "help" in the argument so I would rather set a constant for them all in one go rather than seperately.

```
if(message.content === "help") {
  message.channel.send('Need Help? As a moderator')
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you describe more clearly what you are trying to accomplish, and what issue you are encountering?

Comment: hello thank you! I basically I want it to so using the code I put in the question if someone in my server where my bot is says "help" or "ayuda" they will receive the same results, but I want it to that I can make help and ayuda synonyms for a lack of a better term outside of the argument, so I was thinking as a const using an array or something of the sort! Sorry still learning the jargon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can store all help alternatives in an array and check if user's content exists in that array.

```
const helpStrings = [
  'help',
  'ayuda',
  'another one'
]

if (helpStrings.includes(message.content)) {
    message.channel.send('Need Help? As a moderator')
}
```

Comment: I cant seem to get it to workconst SynString = ['help','ayuda']

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot is online')
})

client.on('message', message=>{

if(SynString.includes(message.content === 'help')){
    message.channel.send('HELP IS HERE!')
}
})

Comment: Not `SynString.includes(message.content === 'help')` just `SynString.includes(message.content)`.

Comment: thank you so much! I know understand the concept! It worked!